# pgsql2shp error: table does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, pgsql2shp

I am exporting tables from Postgresql 9.2 to shapefiles using postgis 2.0. I have the same system on other machines and it works correctly. I have tried running the command from a prompt and get an error about the table not existing, with a truncated version of the name.

```
"path_to_exe/pgsql2shp" -f "..\shapefiles\W06_Exporters_150814_141145_with_geom" -h localhost -u postgres -P
    postgres -p 5432 db_name "select * from analysis.\"W06_Exporters_150814_141145_with_geom\""
```

Comment: I was able to make it work by changing the table name to an SQL statement. Still not sure why it truncates my table name.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't explain or fix anything, but you could try using a temp table:

```
create table temp_for_export as select * from table1 where id < '20'
```

Then

```
pgsql2shp -f [path] -h [myhost] -p [port] -u [user] -P [password] [database] temp_for_export
```

and see what that does.

Is there any chance your host, user or database is incorrect on the pgsql2shp command line, so pgsql2shp is accessing a different "table1" than you're looking at in the shell?